# Alert Dialog in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-drawable

I've implemented a long click listener to delete an entry from my recyclerview and I'd like to give the user one last chance to change their mind. I've done something similar in a 'standard' view using an Alert Dialog and i've made a few drawables for the buttons in the alert view that I would like to use again (to keep a constant interface among all my views)

The drawable I'm using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/minus_button"
      android:state_pressed="false"
      android:state_selected="false"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/add_button"
      android:state_pressed="true"/>

</selector>
```

The alert I'm trying to use is :

```
  public void deleteRequestCheck(final int tempIDval){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to reset all your climbs back to zero?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              deleteEntry(tempIDval);
        }

    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    Button nbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    nbutton.setBackgroundColor(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_tap));
    nbutton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    Button pbutton = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    pbutton.setBackgroundColor(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_tap));
    pbutton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

and I'm calling this from inside my Adapter class (where the longclick action is handled).

The issue I'm having is that

```
 nbutton.setBackgroundColor(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_tap));
 pbutton.setBackgroundColor(getDrawable(R.drawable.button_tap));
```

are giving me an error that it `Cannot resolve method 'getDrawable(int)'`. This has me stumped as this is identical to how I've created and called this alert dialog in my previous activities.

Comment: use `ContextCompat.getColor(yourcontext, R.color.possitive_button_color);`

Comment: Thanks @matrix, slight modification for anyone else. the exact implementation for this would be 
        nbutton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context, R.drawable.button_tap));

Comment: but still I mean this is not the proper way for me. What if you need the same button colors for other dialogs? I would create a theme. I will create an answer

Comment: As it said, `getDrawable()` is belongs to `Context` class, so you can't use it inside an adapter directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 2 ways you can do this:

1) Programmatically like:

```
nbutton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this.context‌​, R.drawable.mypositiveButtonDrawable));
```

But what if you want same button color for other dialogs? Why to duplicate the effort?

2) through styles.xml

Create a theme in your styles.xml like:

```
<style name="DiscardChangesDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonNegative</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/DialogButtonPositive</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogButtonNegative" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dialog_button_negative</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogButtonPositive" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dialog_button_positive</item>
</style>
```

and then use it like:

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.DiscardChangesDialog)
```

and then you do not need to worry about adapter or anything.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: I haven't tried method 2, but method one works for me. Except with `R.drawable.button_tap` instead of `R.color.mypositiveButtonColor`

Comment: yes well I saw that you were trying to set BackgroundColor so that's why I suggested color